# Model Error in CSV import - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, model

I've been racking my brain for a while now and I can't figure out why my csv upload in my rails app is failing. I have a simple model that converts two names in the csv to integers of foreign_ids. The model works completely fine when executed manually in the console but for some reason it fails on the server. I get the error message: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

The model looks as follows:

```
require 'csv'

class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :team
belongs_to :opponent, :foreign_key => 'opponent_id', :class_name => 'Team'   
def self.import(file)
   CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, :header_converters => :symbol) do |row|
    week_hash = row.to_hash 
    teamname = week_hash[:team] 
    teamhash = Team.where(:name => teamname).first 
    teamhash_id = teamhash.id 
    week_newhash = week_hash.reject!{ |k| k == :team} 
    week_newhash[:team_id] = teamhash_id

    opponentname = week_hash[:opponent] 
    opponent_hash = Team.where(:name => opponentname).first 
    hashopponent_id = opponent_hash.id 
    week_newhash = week_newhash.reject!{ |k| k == :opponent} 
    week_newhash[:opponent_id] = hashopponent_id


    Schedule.create!(week_newhash)
  end 
 end 
end
```

The problem must be in here somewhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In which line does the error occurs?

Comment: two possible places `teamhash_id = teamhash.id`  and `hashopponent_id = opponent_hash.id ` and reason is `teamhash` or `opponent_hash` is nil...

Comment: I think the error is that there is no id returner on the hashopponent_id = opponent_hash.id. But I don't understand why.                                       Here is the log from the console.                                                            
  Team Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."name" = $1  ORDER BY "teams"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["name", "Broncos"]]
  Team Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."name" IS NULL  ORDER BY "teams"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/schedules
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

Answer (score 1):

I'm an idiot. The model was fine I just had a column mislabeled in my csv.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change:
`teamhash_id = teamhash.id`
to:
`teamhash_id = teamhash[:id]`, and `hashopponent_id = opponent_hash.id` to `hashopponent_id = opponent_hash[:id]`?